# Meaning of ampersand in method declaration

Tags: c++, methods, reference, qualifiers

I know what a `const` qualifier means in a method declaration (making `*this` const), but I can't fathom what the ampersands in these lines means:

```
MyClass &operator =(const MyClass&) & = default;
//                                  ^- this one
bool operator ==(const MyClass &right) const &;
//                                 that one -^
```

Isn't `decltype(*this)` always `MyClass&` / `const MyClass&`? So what does the ampersand mean in here?

Comment: This means the method can only be called on an lvalue of `MyClass` type (as opposed to an rvalue). So that one can't do `MyClass() = my_class_instance` or `functionReturningMyClass() = my_class_instance`. Similarly, `&&` after closing paren means "only callable on rvalue".

Comment: To the down voter: Ever tried to google for special characters? Doesn't work very well. @IgorTandetnik, why didn't you put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Kay likely because he knew it would be dupe-hammered and wanted to avoid posting a duplicate answer on a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. So what does the ampersand mean in here?

It means [ref-qualified member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions):

> A non-static member function can be declared with either an lvalue ref-qualifier (the token & after the function name) or rvalue ref-qualifier (the token && after the function name). During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of class X is treated as a function that takes an implicit parameter of type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X if it has no ref-qualifiers or if it has the lvalue ref-qualifier. Otherwise (if it has rvalue ref-qualifier), it is treated as a function taking an implicit parameter of type rvalue reference to cv-qualified X.

You can define both (lvalue/rvalue ref-qualifier), and the appropriate one will be picked up by overload resolution. Such as:

```
bool operator ==(const MyClass &right) const &;
bool operator ==(const MyClass &right) const &&;
```

> 2. Isn't decltype(*this) always MyClass& / const MyClass&?

Note the type of `*this` won't change even in the rvalue ref-qualified function.

> Note: unlike cv-qualification, ref-qualification does not change the properties of the `this` pointer: within a rvalue ref-qualified function, `*this` remains an lvalue expression.